# Realm shuffle objects after deleating

Tags: android, realm

In my project I am using Realm 1.0.0 with multiple tables there. I founded issue in deleting object from table, it shuffles other objects after deleating one. I mean if I have, for example 3 objects obj1, obj2 and obj3 and I delete obj3 Realm returns me other objects in wrong order (obj2, obj1). For deleting I am using this one simple line:

```
        realm.where(MessageElement.class).equalTo("userId", userId).findAll().deleteAllFromRealm();
```

Can any one tell solution to keep order of rest objects correct?

Comment: Define a field called `rank` and sort based on that? Or use `findAllSorted()`

Comment: *Can any one tell solution to keep order of rest objects correct?* but it is correct ... as you didn't sort it anyway ... also why you depends on order?

Comment: Selvin, But why it shuffles records after delete? It doesn't have sense. If I would use Sqlite i won't have this like issue, cause it doesn't touch all other records except that one which I want to delete. And it depends me on order cause it shuffles all other elements in my list

Comment: Realms and RealmResults are unordered i.e., you should not assume that objects retain their position. As already mentioned, sorting is your best option.

Comment: But why i get correct order before deleting? After receiving from server I write it to realm and read it after when I need it and it reads correct...

Comment: That is caused by our internal optimisations. So even though you objects might accidentally be in order, you cannot rely on it unless you specify a sorting order. As @geisshirt wrote, you should specify a sorting if sorting is important. Just use `findAllSorted("field", Sort.ASC)`